# Android Toggle Button notification

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications, android-togglebutton

I am trying to set a toggle button that will enable and disable notification for the app i am building.
The current code i have it set up for an old password field as I was using thenewboston Android Tutorial.
This is My Current Code:

```
package com.example.smartfood;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Settings extends Activity {

Button chkCmd;
ToggleButton notTog;
EditText input;
TextView display;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);      
    notTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbResult);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbResult);
    notTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (notTog.isChecked()){
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT  | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }else{
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: And what exactly is your question? You've shown us some code and told us what you want to do, but you haven't asked any question.

Comment: I am unsure what code I need, I was looking for some sort of advice on what to use, I'm a new android developer and am unsure how to enable this function